# Malformed request from aiohttp.ClientSession().post() with multiple image files

Tags: python-asyncio, multipartform-data, aiohttp

I'm still relatively new to Python and my first time to use **aiohttp** so I'm hoping someone can help spot where my problem is.

I have a function that does the following:

1. retrieves from the JSON payload two base64 strings - `base64Front` and `base64Back`
2. decode them, save to "images" folder
3. send the `Front.jpg` and `Back.jpg` to an external API
4. this external API expects a `multipart/form-data`

```
imgDataF = base64.b64decode(base64FrontStr)
frontFilename = 'images/Front.jpg'
with open(frontFilename, 'wb') as frontImgFile:
    frontImgFile.write(imgDataF)

imgDataB = base64.b64decode(base64BackStr)
backFilename = 'images/Back.jpg'
with open(backFilename, 'wb') as backImgFile:
    backImgFile.write(imgDataB)

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'AccountAccessKey': 'some-access-key', 
    'SecretToken': 'some-secret-token'
}

url = 'https://external-api/2.0/AuthenticateDoc'
files = [('file', open('./images/Front.jpg', 'rb')), 
         ('file', open('./images/Back.jpg', 'rb'))]

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.post(url, data=files, headers=headers) as resp:
        print(resp.status)
        print(await resp .json())
```

The response I'm getting is status code 400 with:

```
{'ErrorCode': 1040, 'ErrorMessage': 'Malformed/Invalid Request detected'}
```

If I call the url via Postman and send the two jpg files, I get status code 200.
Hope someone can help here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FormData to construct your request. Remove the content type from header and use it in FormData field as below:

```
data = FormData()
data.add_field('file',
               open('Front.jpg', 'rb'),
               filename='Front.jpg',
               content_type='multipart/form-data')

await session.post(url, data=data)
```

Reference: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#post-a-multipart-encoded-file